How to create linked service in Azure data factory for on premise Rest API
I have an on premise API which is only accessible within private network. I have to create a linked service of this API for a client. For testing purpose I created a simple flask API in python running on my local host 8080 port. When I try to create linked service in ADF i get this error:
The connection to the REST service failed. Endpoint= http://local host:8080, Reason=
Access to local host is denied, resolved IP address is local host, network type is OnPremise

How can i resolve this issue? I have created self hosted integration runtime instance for adf as well. I tried adding an inbound rule in firewall for 8080 port, but it didn't work.

Did you create your SHIR in the same network where your API is accessible

@Aswin Yes SHIR is installed on my laptop where my API is also running. They are in same network

Did you try testing the connection in SHIR itself?

@Aswin How can i do this?

I was able to resolve this issue. In cmd change directory to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared> and run these command as admin:
.\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation
.\dmgcmd.exe -EnableLocalMachineAccess
Also you need to add inbound rule in firewall for your port of API. In my case it is 8080 and the connection test was successful in ADF.


You can check the connection directly in the integration runtime manager only. Below are the steps to check.

Open Integration runtime configuration manager.
Click Diagnostics tab in the dialog box.
Click Data source type as others.
Give the connection details as Json format in linked service JSON text box.
Test the connection.


If test connection is passed, it means this integration runtime is not connected properly with the correct data factory.

I checked this and everything is fine. In Linked service when i provide my public IP from ISP in url. Connection is successful from SHIR and i am able to get api data. But not on private IP. SHIR is working and i have connected the correct data factory. Need solution for this private IP.

Private ip means accesible only on the network where SHIR is installed, right?

Yes, for testing purpose I installed SHIR on my laptop and connected it to my test data factory. My flask api is running on laptop where SHIR is installed. But i can't access this in linked service when i use this as URL: http://192.168.2.136:8080/api/data. If i give my public IP from ISP, I am able to connect to API. This is a test for a client API, which is accessible inside their network only.
